# How an object will call toString method implicitly?

Tags: java

If I am printing an object of the class then it is printing the `toString()` method implementation even I am not writing the `toString()` method so what are the implementation,how it is calling `toString()` internally?

Comment: What do you mean by *printing the `toString()` method implementation*?

Answer (score 59):

You're not explicitly calling `toString()`, but implicitly you are:

See:

```java
System.out.println(foo); // foo is a non primitive variable
```

[`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a class, with a `static` field [`out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), of type [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). So you're calling the [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) method of a `PrintStream`.

It is implemented like this:

```java
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

As we see, it's calling the [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method.
This is implemented as follows:

```java
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

And here you see, that [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is called.

Answer (score 9):

Every object in Java **IS-A**(n) `Object` as well. Hence, if a `toString()` implementation has not been provided by a class the default `Object.toString()` gets invoked automatically.

`Object.toString()`'s ***default implementation*** simply prints the object's class name followed by the object's hash code which isn't very helpful. So, one should usually override `toString()` to provide a more meaningful String representation of an object's runtime state.

> even I am not writing the toString() method so what are the implementation,how it is calling toString() internally?

`toString()` is one of the few methods (like `equals()`, `hashCode()` etc.) that gets ***called implicitly*** under certain programmatic situations like (just naming a few)

- printing an object using `println()`
- printing a `Collection` of objects *(`toString()` is invoked on all the elements)*
- concatenation with a String *(like `strObj = "My obj as string is " + myObj;`)*

Answer (score 5):

Everything inherits from Object, so the [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) on Object will be called if you have not defined one.

Comment: And Type :).  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html

Comment: A method will be only called when we call it explicitly ,but  here if we are printing an object ,toString()is called  how it is possible?

Comment: @MarounMaroun You mean Primitives type not inherited from Object class? Is Object class have any primitive type?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Exactly. `Object` class doesn't have primitive types, but does have wrappers - Look for `Integer`, `Double`..

Answer (score 0):

toString() method is present in Object class, so when u put obj in System.out.println(obj);, impliciyly it will call toString() present in Object class since every user created class will implicitly inherits Object class so as ur newly created class, that means that toString() is available in ur class so it will print something like for example: "PkgNamePackage.Classname@12cf4"
However if u explicitely override toString method and give ur own implementation then it will written the string what ever u give in Overriden tostring method();
ex:

```
public class DogArray {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Im the newly created Object";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DogArray d1 = new DogArray();
        System.out.println(d1);
    }
}

output: Im the newly created Object
```

Answer (score -1):

In java object class is super class to the each and every class.whenever your passing parameter to the system.out.println internally object class to string method will be excuted.it returns class name@reference value given but as per our application requirement object class to string method will override in collection and string class.it returns their content.