# use toString() to convert URI to String led to android app crash

Tags: android, crash, uri, tostring

I want set Notification ring ，this is my code ：

```
Notification notification = new Notification();     

String ringName = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
            MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).toString();

notification.sound = Uri.parse(ringName);
```

but i find that  .toString()  will led  app crash in emulater.

"RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
        MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)" return  NULL ,because  emulater  set notification ring  is silent.

So i  guest that  if  URI is NULL  , we can's use  Uri.toString()  to convert URI to String ?

yes, i make a test to prove my guess . Because this android emulator set ringtone , notification ,alarm to be silent and there is no music file in emulator.

so first i use

```
abd to push 1.mp3 to sdcard/notification/
```

then go to

```
"dev tool -->media provider-->scan sdcard --> insert abulm . and go to android --> system setting-->sound-->set notification to 1.mp3"
```

and run my code again , there is no problem come out.

So, if URI is NULL , we can't use Uri.toString() to convert uri to string, this will get a nullpoint error.

But why ? i hope someone that could give a detail explain ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good explanation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051481/how-an-object-will-call-tostring-method-implicitly) about the `toString()` method. You could add an if statement.

```
 if (ringName != null) {
        notification.sound = Uri.parse(ringName);
    }
```

Comment: NO,  when  `RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
            MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION) == NULL` ,   using   `toString`  will make app crash  .so   `ringName != null  ` won't be  excuted