# Implicitly calling a method in a class from main

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

I am new to Java and I am trying to solve an exercise given by my professor.
He has given this class

```
public class MioPunto {
public int x;
public int y;
public String toString() {
    return ("[" + x + "," + y + "]");
  }
}
```

and I am supposed to write another class with a main method. Into the main I have to print the coordinates without explicitly calling the "toString" method.
I unconsciously solved it in this way

```
public class TestMioPunto{
public static void main(String[] args){
    MioPunto inizio = new MioPunto();
    MioPunto fine = new MioPunto();
    inizio.x=10;
    inizio.y=10;
    fine.x=20;
    fine.y=30;
    System.out.println("Inizio: " + inizio + "\n" + "Fine: " + fine);
  }
}
```

and the output is [image]
I can't understand how Java automatically called the toString method (brackets and commas), can you please explain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17051779/6007441

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java calls `toString` when you use `+` on a `String` and an object.

So your

```
System.out.println("Inizio: " + inizio + "\n" + "Fine: " + fine);
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println("Inizio: " + inizio.toString() + "\n" + "Fine: " + fine.toString());
```

**except** that if `inizio` or `fine` is `null`, the first won't give you an error (you'll see `null` in the string instead) but the second will.

From the JLS's section on [the String Concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

which refers to the [String Conversion section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), which says (after discussing converting primitives to string):

> ...
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null" is used instead.

Comment: I should have realized it was a duplicate! There are very, very few non-duplicate beginner Java questions...

Answer (score 1):

Since `java.lang.Object` is an implicit base class of `MioPunto` (because it is a base class of all Java objects), method `MioPunto.toString()` is an *override* of [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method.

Since all objects have an implementation of `toString()`, Java compiler can freely add an invocation of `toString()` on any object in a chain of string concatenations performed with the `+` operator:

> The string concatenation operator `+` (§15.18.1), which, when given a `String` operand and a reference, will convert the reference to a `String` by invoking the `toString` method of the referenced object (using `"null"` if either the reference or the result of `toString` is a `null` reference), and then will produce a newly created `String` that is the concatenation of the two strings.