# Why does the "this" keyword print exactly what toString() is printing?

Tags: java, this, tostring

Why does the `this` keyword print exactly what the `toString` method is printing?

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Stuff s = new Stuff("in",5 );
      System.out.println(s);

      double doubleValue = 2.5 ;
      s.doSomething(doubleValue);
      System.out.println(doubleValue);

      s = new Stuff("more", 3);
      String str = "word";
      System.out.println(s.changeSomething(str));
      System.out.println(s);
      System.out.println(str);
   }
}

class Stuff {
    private static final int n =2 ;
    private String string;
    private int num;

    public Stuff(String s, int num) {
        this.num = num;
        string = s;
    }

    public void doSomething(double d) {
        d = d * num;
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public double changeSomething(String s) {
        s = string;
        return n * num;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return string + " has " + num;
    }
}
```

This is the output I get

```
in has 5
in has 5
2.5
6.0
more has 3
word
```

Comment: As Martin said, basically `println(this)` just calls the `toString()` method and prints it.

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17051707/2711811

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println` method does not know how to output an instance of a custom type, so the next best thing it can do is to call the `toString` method, which is available on all objects in Java and returns the string representation. In this case you have overridden it, so it actually executes your `toString` method and prints the result.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that there is such a layer of indirection :-) .

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation of `System.out.println()`. [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a `PrintStream`. [`PrintStream::println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) calls [`PrintStream::print(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.Object-), which calls [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-), which returns the string `"null"` if the reference is null; otherwise returns `obj.toString()`.